# When I click on Gmail, only one of my accounts show -how do I access the other one?

Tags: google-account

I used to see the account on my google bar, it disappeared. I set up a second account and it now appears on the bar, but not the original one.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on your name on the right in the second top bar

You should see the additional account name there (as long as you are logged into both accounts). If not, click the Add Account button.

You may find this Google Answer helpful too.

http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1721977